# Deleting data from table - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create a delete modal box and not with the basic alert with JS. Below, i have placed the modal box in the for loop in the table purposely to delete each entry respectively..

when i click on the delete link, it doesn't pop up the modal box? Why is this happening?

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-xl mb-0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>File</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach($entries as $entry)
    <tr>
      <td>{{$entry->id}}</td>
      <td>{{$entry->file}}</td>
      <td>
        <a href="/file/{{$entry->id}}/checks"></a>
        <a href="#deleteModal_{{ $entry->id }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></a>

        <div id="deleteModal_{{ $entry->id }}" class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog">

            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
              </div>

              <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Do you wish to delete this {{$entry->name}} file?</p>
              </div>

              <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="'/files/{{$entry->id}}/delete'" class="yes">Yes</a>
                <a data-dismiss="modal" class="no">No</a>      
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>         
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Btw, there is 1 additional `</div>`, which hasn't got defined start of the tag-pair. Not sure if typo during copying or actual problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace below two line

```
   <a  href="#"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal_{{ $entry->id }}"></a>

   <div id="deleteModal_{{ $entry->id }}" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
```

You have to add modal path in data-target attribute of anchor tag href attribute wit # and remove id="myModal" from div

Answer (score 0):

You have twice the id defined in the modal div

```
 id="deleteModal_{{ $entry->id }}" class="modal fade" id="myModal"
```

Remove the second id and rename

```
data-target="#myModal"
```

to

```
data-target="#deleteModal_{{ $entry->id }}"
```

Comment: i had that line in there to pass the id to the modal to get the id of the respective entry that i click.

Comment: You're doing data-target="#myModal" but myModal can't be found because only the first instance of ID counts. You have have to do data-target="#deleteModal_{{ $entry->id }}" then.